# Running a for loop around an SPTRequest block with Spotify iOS SDK 3.0

Tags: ios, spotify

I'm running a for loop around a block that requests data from the Spotify servers. When tracksLoaded is called, sometimes everything has been executed within the block, and other times it skips over one or more requests. A sleep helps the situation, but I'm pretty sure there must be a better way to handle this.

```
//From each given array of countryURLs, generate a playlist of songs
- (void)generatePlaylistFromURL:(NSMutableArray *)countryURLS {

NSMutableArray *regionPlaylist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//loop through all the Countries in one Region
for (int k=0; k<[countryURLS count]; k++) {
    sleep(.2);
    //request playlist from Country URI
    [SPTRequest requestItemAtURI:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"spotify:user:funkytrumpet:playlist:" stringByAppendingString:[[countryURLS objectAtIndex:k] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"][6]]]
                        withSession:session
                        callback:^(NSError *error, id object) {

                        if (error != nil) {
                            NSLog(@"*** Playlist lookup got error %@", error);
                            NSLog(@"id of playlist error:%@", [[countryURLS objectAtIndex:k] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"][6]);
                            return;
                        }

                            //loop through all tracks in one Country and create array of track URIs
                            for (int i = 0; i < [[[object firstTrackPage] items] count]; i++) {

                                //NSLog(@"playlist: %@", [[[object firstTrackPage] items] objectAtIndex:(i)]);


                                [regionPlaylist addObject:[[[object firstTrackPage] items] objectAtIndex:(i)]];


                            }


                            //only play next track if this is the last album to load
                            if (k == ([countryURLS count]-1)) {
                                [self tracksLoaded:(regionPlaylist)];
                            }


    }];



}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sleeping is horrid. Two solutions jump to mind.

First is to load the URLs serially using what can sort of be described as an asynchronous recursive loop. Pseudocode (don't expect it to compile, but you should get the idea):

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSMutableArray *urisToLoad;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSMutableArray *loadedObjects;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.loadedObjects = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.urisToLoad = …;
    [self recursivelyLoadObjects];
}

-(void)recursivelyLoadObjects {

    if (self.urisToLoad.count == 0) {
        [self objectsDone];
        return;
    }

    id nextURI = self.urisToLoad[0];
    [self.urisToLoad removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    [SPTRequest requestItemAtURI:nextURI
                     withSession:session
                        callback:^(NSError *error, id object) {

        // You should probably error check and stuff here.
        [self.loadedObjects addObject:object];
        [self recursivelyLoadObjects];
    }];

}

-(void)objectsDone {
    // All of the objects are now loaded (or failed to load)
    NSLog(@"%@", self.loadedObjects);
}
```

The second solution is to learn reactive programming using a library like ReactiveCocoa. You can set up a chain of signals that load each URI, then get notified when all the signals have fired.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented the recursive option and it works well.

Comment: Cool, good to know. Please upvote/accept this answer as correct!